# best way to manage bootstrap in python flask project

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have created a web app using python-Flask and frontend using bootstrap. This app allows user to browse the AWS S3 bucket from web browser. Please excuse me this project is still is construction phase and I'm in learning path. I have manually downloaded the bootstrap code and placed it in `static` folder.

here is the [link](https://github.com/amjad489/pys3browser) for the project.
https://github.com/amjad489/pys3browser

I want to know if there is a way where we can run a command it will upgrade the bootstrap and its dependencies.

Thanks in advance for your help!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Bower](https://bower.io/) for managing your web packages. It is written for *node js* so you need to install this as well. This is a very common way to manage your frontend packages like jQuery, Bootstrap, ...

Comment: I'm too eager to do that, sorry I don't have enough reputation to do that.